# What are the benefits of cmake over make for single platform project

Tags: makefile, cmake, gnu-make

If there is a relatively large project that is entirely build using `Makefile`s is it wort it to replace make with `cmake`? Everybody makes emphasis that `cmake` makes it easier to support cross-platform development but in make case target platform is just one and there is no plans to change it. What benefits would I have from `cmake` in this particular scenario?

Comment: This is not the first attempt to ask about benefits of CMake over Make in a "very simple single-platform case". Actually, CMake provides much more than multi-platform development. You could take any list of advantages of CMake, and eliminate a single point from it.

Comment: Well, cmake generates makefiles.  So everything cmake does, can be done in makefiles.  The reverse is not always true: some things that are quite trivial to do in makefiles can be very difficult to do in cmake.  cmake does a lot of things for you so you don't have to write complex makefiles--but yours are already written.  For a project that's already implemented in makefiles you need to ask yourself what you hope to gain by switching.  If your makefiles do what you want and are solid, it's just wasted effort to convert them.  If they have problems, maybe cmake will help.

Comment: @MadScientist *"Well, cmake generates makefiles. So everything cmake does, can be done in makefiles."* This reasoning is flawed for one simple reason: The makefiles generated by cmake include calls to the cmake command line tool which means there may be functionality involved that may not be available in makefiles, unless you've got cmake installed on your system.

Comment: @fabian That is true in theory, but in practice it isn't.  The cmake calls are done only to provide some level of abstraction from the operating system: things like removing files, making directories, etc.  See the output of `cmake -E --help` to view the operations that makefiles generated by cmake might invoke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. CMake is also good at finding dependencies. Take OpenMP, TBB, and MPI, which are very common to get stuff executed in parallel. CMake offers comfortable ways to check which of these libraries are present. You get a variable to use add includes and libraries to your targets and you are done. If you want to know within your C, C++ code (or whatever you use) which library is present, CMake offers way to pass pre-processor macros to the compiler command.
2. CMakeLists.txt files are more indirect compared to Makefiles. This makes them harder to read and understand. With a growing project size, it turns into an advantage, because you have to make a change at one or fewer points.
3. With CTest it is easy to include a basic testing.
4. There are modules (CMake code files) you can include in your project. This can help find you dependencies, automate Qt's moc (included in CMake already) or build your documentation (Sphinx, JavaDoc, Doxygen, LaTeX). With Make, most of the time you end up writing your own code.

Sure, you can do everything with make, but it takes much more effort. The larger your project grows and the more targets and dependencies you get, the more a full-fledged build system pays off. This is not only true for CMake, but also for Meson, Waf and so on.

Comment: I don't disagree with this but I will say: translating a complex makefile project into cmake is not always easy.  Make gives you a lot of flexibility to do things which cmake can make very difficult.  If your system is a straightforward compilation it's fine but the more "advanced" things you need to do, like DSLs that generate source files, fancy linker operations like generating linker maps, etc. the more you'll struggle with the limitations cmake imposes.

Comment: @usr1234567 You may want to add CPack/installation functionality to your answer.

Comment: @fabian Last time I tried, I was disappointed by the RPM packages from CPack. So I don't see it as an advantage.